# How to structure a presentation for a Post Doctoral Research Fellowship

Tags: research-process, funding

After the initial peer review stage, most research fellowships (for example RCUK or ERC grants) have a final interview stage primarily assessing the qualities of the candidate. Alongside the interview it is typical to give a short talk around 10 minutes in length. What points should the talk focus on to give the best chances for success?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your host institution might offer some advice on this, possibly also including the opportunity to practice your interview before a panel of people who have sat on grant assessment boards.

Otherwise, take the hint from the time allocated to you. There is little point in going into any details of your proposed research. When I went through the interview for a similar grant, I posed and answered the following questions:

**What?**
Very briefly, and for a general audience, describe the proposed research.

**Why You?**
Express why you are the right person for the job. Your background, skills, networks.

**Why Now?**
Why should this research be done now?

**Why Here?**
Why should you be doing the research at *insert host institution*, in particular?